# Placing If and Else in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Linq If Statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443152/linq-if-statement)

I am trying to run a query using Linq, but before the where clause I wanted to specify the If condition but I am not getting proper syntax(may be) or is it not possible?
I have searched a lot but they use if and else before query, but I want If within query.
Is it possible like:

```
var q = (from mortgageapplication in context.MortgageApplications
         if(mortgageapplication.purpose of loan==7)
         {
              where mortgageapplication.MortgageActive == true && mortgageapplication.MortgageCoordinator==ID
         }
```

I am just trying but let me know if we can place if before where?

Comment: Good question, but have a look here from some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443152/linq-if-statement

Comment: The very purpose of the `where` part of a Linq statement is to evaluate conditions on the collection's items. Just put it in there: `where mortgageapplication.purposeofloan == 7 && mortgageapplication.MortgageActive == true && mortgageapplication.MortgageCoordinator==ID`

Comment: This was the incomplete demo I had given actually when if condition satisfies then in where I compare the different dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would be logically equivalent:

```
var loanPurpose = 7;
var coordinatorId = ...;
var query =
    from app in context.MortgageApplications
    where app.PurposeOfLoan != loanPurpose
        || (app.MortgageActive && app.MortgageCoordinator == coordinatorId)
    select application;
```

The logic goes as follows, you only want to check if it is active and by the given coordinator.  Otherwise get any application.

Comment: Loanpurpose may have different values like at one time '2' or other '7' so in where condition I can compare different fields based on Loan purpose value.